# Database Insert into script preparation for tests (logging data state?)

Tags: database, oracle, testing

It is hard to formulate question in title so I'll try to explain.

I need to do automatic UI tests for application which is already written. These application has a big testing database loaded with a lot of data. Sometimes it is hard to understand relationships between tables as they are not trivial also there are foreign keys missing (logic is implemented in Java application, some logic is in stored procedures).
Problem is, that I can run my tests only once: after they are finished, some data is moved and some of data is deleted by application. So I need to prepare scripts and do Insert Into statements before every test.

Is it possible to make such a script preparing easier? Of course, good solution will be to investigate all db structure and dependencies (or review application logic in Java), but it would take a lot of time. I cannot save database data and look for the changes after tests are finished as it will take a lot of time for data export/import in SQL Developer. Maybe DB administrator have another Oracle DB tools for doing this?

Comment: One possible solution is to write database audit. By this it is possible to see all specific queries are launched at DB. Search for oracle auditing and DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL for extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you obtain and use a good testing framework. They're usually free. For Java the standard is JUnit. For PL/SQL, I like utPlsql but there are several others available. Using the testing framework you can insert the needed data into the database at the start of the test, run the test, and make sure the end results are as expected, then clean up the data so you can run the test again cleanly. This requires a fair amount of coding to make it all work right, but it's much easier to do this coding once than to perform the same tasks manually many times over.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for response. 
You are completely right, it is better to start with empty tables and fill them for example with DBUnit, then, after tests to do clean up. Problem is, as you mentioned, time for setup. Also now I'm not sure which tables are affected by my tests (so problem will stays - I'll need long database and logic investigation, but maybe it is only one solution).

Comment: Given your description of the problems you're facing it appears that writing some unit tests would be very helpful.  In order to do the manual testing you're going through the exact same process needed to create some automated unit tests, but you're forced to repeat the manual process over and over.  Good luck.

Comment: Agree about importance of unit tests. In these situation Unit tests exists, they was written by programmers with mocks, not real data. Also as I mentioned, these functionality is implemented before, so it is impossible to turn back time and create UI automation tests before or in parallel with programming.